# Trying to re-arrange pages of a PDF in a sorted order

Tags: sorting, pdf

I have a program (Shipstation) that provides me with packing lists as a PDF document (one page per order). Shipstation sorts by order number, and doesn't allow me to sort the pages any other way.

I wondering if there is a way to rearrange pages so they are sorted by first name of the recipient?

I'm including a link to an [example packing list here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjx48hwin888e0z/TestPackingSlip635410218432002762.pdf).

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Sort your abstract pages such that you have an array/list such that the 0th element is an integer representing the actual page that should go there

Step 2: Using a PDF toolkit of some kind, reorder the document

Now, let's talk about step 1 - let's assume that you have the data that you want in something like this:

```
public class Invoice {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now you would have List and you could easily sort it by OrderNumber.  If you do this, the order of your list should correspond to pages in the output PDF.

If you resort by FirstName into a different list, you can now generate the page transitions as a list or array of int.

Step 2: this is going to depend on what toolkit you use. I'm sure you could use iText or docotoic.pdf, but I'm going to use [DotPdf](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotpdf/) or JoltPdf as examples libraries (mostly because I wrote them and this is a slam-dunk task):

```
public static void ResortPdf(Stream inPdf, Stream outPdf, List<int> pageTransitions)
{
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(inPdf, null, null); // no passwords - but maybe you need that?
    PdfPage[] originalPages = doc.Pages.ToArray();
    for (int i=0; i < pageTransitions.Count; i++) {
        doc.Pages[i] = originalPages[pageTransitions[i]];
    }
    doc.Save(outPdf);
}
```